# ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground caches results without my consent

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

I am trying to call a cloud function, at multiple stages of my app (with no arguments), however, when I try to call it the second time, it immediately returns the (cached) results from my first call. I verified this behavior by putting my device to airplane mode before executing the second call, and it immediately returned without error, with the same results from the first call. I haven't enabled caching or pinning anywhere, I need Parse to call that function every time I need, without caching. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Never heard of this due to parse.com.  I wonder if the cache is happening somewhere on the stack between your app and parse.com

Comment: @danh I haven't set anything special like a URL caching system or anything. In iOS, I do the exact same thing and it works correct.